# Useful extension of links with jQuery wrap method

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<ul>

<li class="list">
<a href="link1"> Text1 </a>

<li class="list">
<a href="link2"> Text2 </a>

</ul>
```

Now I want to link not only the text, but the complete `<li>` - element with the link that is already in the `<a>` - element.

I thought about jQuery and included the following script:

```
jQuery(".list").wrap("<a href='static_URL'></a>");
```

Linking already works with the jQuery code. I just don't know how to get the URL from the `<a>` - tag as a variable and replace it with the "static_url".

Comment: Note that that will result in invalid HTML; the only valid child of a `<ul>` is an `<li>`, not an `<a>` (likewise the only valid parents for an `<li>` are `<ul>` or `<ol>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much I understood your question you want to wrap every list item in an anchor tag and you want that anchor URL as the main container URL? if this was the question than this resolves your problem.

```js
$(".list").each((i, list) => {
    let url = $(list).find("a").attr('href');
   $(list).wrap(`<a href="${url}"></a>`);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

<li class="list">
<a href="link1"> Text1 </a>

<li class="list">
<a href="link2"> Text2 </a>

</ul>
```